# wordpress php can't return value from database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am building a plugin that determines if a user is signed up to an affiliates program and if not, it shows a dashboard widget.

Here is the function I am using to determine if the current user is signed up to the affiliates program:

```
function is_affiliate() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $is_affiliate = "SELECT enable_affiliate FROM {$wpdb->base_prefix}usermeta WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
    return;
}
```

The output should either be "yes or "no", based on the output I create a dashboard widget as follows:

```
if(is_affiliate() != 'yes') {

// Dashboard widget goes here

}
```

However, my initial function to determine if the current user is signed up is not returning anything. Is there something blatently obviously wrong with my code?

Comment: Coding a string with an SQL QUERY in it _does not a database access make._

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly - do you have any advice on how I go about achieving what I need to? I'm looking at the wordpress $wpdb->get_var() function but with no luck

Comment: Yea sure.https://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly - do you perhaps any more specific direction - not sure the "user manual" would count as a decent answer - may as well have just put google.com as your answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [get_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) to retrieve that value. The WordPress API already has what you need.

To answer your question, though, you need to look at the [global wpdb object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) which can prepare & execute queries for you.

Comment: Thanks @csixty - I literally just clocked onto this method - works a treat, thanks